# How can I use Redux `connect` from inside a React component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-functional-component

Let us stipulate that the inscrutable exhortations of my soul have moved me to build a React component that wraps a call to Redux [`connect`](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate), like this:

```
// ReduxWrapper.tsx

import React from 'react'
import {connect, useStore} from 'react-redux'

interface SomeOtherComponentProps {
    foo?: string,
    bar?: string
}

function SomeOtherComponent({foo, bar}: SomeOtherComponentProps) {
    return (
        <div>
            This is a component with foo={foo} and bar={bar}!
        </div>
    )
}

export default function ReduxWrapper(
    child_props: SomeOtherComponentProps
): React.ReactElement {
    const store = useStore()
    const mapStateToProps = (state: {}) => ({
        // @ts-ignore
        foo: state.foo
    });

    return connect(
        mapStateToProps, {}
    )(SomeOtherComponent)(child_props) as React.ReactElement<any, string | React.JSXElementConstructor<any>>
}
```

```
// App.tsx

const store = makeStoreCorrectly()

...

return (
   <Provider store={store}>
       <ReduxWrapper bar="baz" />
   </Provider>
)
```

For the purposes of this question let's not ask *why* I want to do this or whether it's a good idea. Can it be done? I can't figure out how to make the call to `connect` here work properly. (In this current form, I get a `TypeError: Object(...)(...)(...) is not a function`.)

Comment: This is obviously an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem?newreg=3110b0eeeeaa436880c170012ba2ae22) and you know it: `let's not ask why I want to do this` you may want to look at custom hooks instead.

Answer (score 2):

> For the purposes of this question let's not ask why I want to do this or whether it's a good idea.

To be very clear:: **No, you should *not* do this, and it's *not* a good idea!**

The issue is that each call to `connect` creates a new *component type*, and [you should **never create a new component type *while rendering*!**](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2020/05/blogged-answers-a-mostly-complete-guide-to-react-rendering-behavior/#component-types-and-reconciliation).  Every time React sees a new component type in the same place compared to the last render, it will destroy and throw away that component instance *and* all of the DOM nodes that were rendered by that child.

The *only* way you could even hypothetically get away with this and have it "work" would be to memoize the creation of the component:

```js
const MyConnectedComponent = useMemo(() => {
  return connect()(MyComponent);
}, [])

return <MyConnectedComponent />
```

But this is still not a good idea.

Besides, if you have the hooks API available, I'm not sure why you would even want to consider doing something like this with `connect` anyway.

If you can provide some more details I might be able to offer more specific advice.

Comment: (for context: this answer has been brought to you by the person that implemented connect as well as the hooks. take it seriously)

Answer (score 0):

Remember that `connect` don't actually return a React Element, but a Component instead.

```
export default function ReduxWrapper(props) {
  // try to keep the same identity of `ReduxComponent` across re-renders
  // every time this change, the component re-mount.
  const ReduxComponent = React.useMemo(
    () => connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SomeOtherComponent),
    []
  );
  
  return React.createElement(ReduxComponent, props);
}
```